# how to try out onunload on website

Tags: javascript, html

Ok so im trying to use the `onload` and `onunload` for the
body, but is there a way to try out the `onunload`-event in Chrome ?

Is there someway to "simulate" the `onunload` ?

Answer (score 0):

`window.dispatchEvent('onload'); window.dispatchEvent('onunload');`

Quoting from [the MDN article for `.dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent):

> Dispatches an Event at the specified `EventTarget`, invoking the
>   affected `EventListener`s in the appropriate order. The normal event
>   processing rules (including the capturing and optional bubbling phase)
>   apply to events dispatched manually with `dispatchEvent()`.